# Linux kernel driver: Finish 'completion' when device is removed

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, kernel-module

I am writing a kernel driver to send/receive data with a PCI Express device. For this first version of the driver I am creating a character device interface where the user can read data using a file.

### Background

I want to implement a blocking read where the user requests data and the driver populates a user buffer. In order to block the user's `read` call, I am using a [`completion`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/completion.h) structure.

When the driver is loaded and the user requests a read the driver blocks as expected. If I were to finish the read then everything runs fine.

### The problem

In order to be safe, whenever the module is removed I call the `complete_all` function, just in case someone removes the module or device in the middle of a read transaction.

Neither the `remove` or `exit` function is called and both the module and user application is blocked. I've tried the following three functions (shown with their associated result).

1. `wait_completion(&dev->read_complete);` //Blocks indefinitely, I need to reset the computer
2. `retval = wait_for_completion_interruptible(&dev->read_complete);` //I can kill the user application manually and then remove the driver
3. `retval = wait_for_completion_killable(&dev->read_complete);` //Same as interruptible

My expectation is that when the remove function is called I can call `complete_all(&dev->read_complete)` and the read function will return an error.

In order to remove external factors I've made a repo on github, so if anyone wants to see the behavior for themselves they just need to clone and follow the instructions:

[Kernel Module Completion Test](https://github.com/CospanDesign/kernel-module/tree/completion-test)

The relevant parts of the module are here (/src/mymodule.c)

```
typedef struct {
  struct cdev cdv;
  struct class *cls;
  struct device *dev;
  struct completion complete;
} mymodule_t;
mymodule_t mymod;


//Sysfs 'mymodule_test' attribute (all but the actual function is left out for brevity)

static ssize_t mymodule_test_store(struct device *dev, struct device_attribute *attr, const char *buf, size_t count)
{
  int retval = 0;
  int value = 0;
  if (sscanf(buf, "%d", &value) == 1)
  {
    retval = strlen(buf);
  }
  if (value)
  {
    printk("Value is: %d\n", value);
    if (!completion_done(&mymod.complete))
    {
      complete(&mymod.complete);
    }
    printk("Sent Completion\n");
  }

  return retval;
}

//FOPS (all but 'read' function is left out for brevity)

ssize_t mymodule_read(struct file *filp, char * buf, size_t count, loff_t *f_pos)
{
  printk("Read!\n");
  if (completion_done(&mymod.complete))
  {
    reinit_completion(&mymod.complete);
  }

  printk("Wait for Completion\n");
  wait_for_completion_interruptible(&mymod.complete);
  printk("After Completion\n");
  return 0;
}


static int __init mymodule_init(void)
{
  ...
  //Register class and device
  //Configure character driver with fops
  init_completion(&mymod.complete);
  ...
}
static void __exit mymodule_exit(void)
{
  ...
  if (!completion_done(&mymod.complete))
  {
    printk("Send a completion!\n");
    complete(&mymod.complete);
  }
  //Clean up the rest of the module
  ...
}
module_init(mymodule_init);
module_exit(mymodule_exit);
```

Here is the userland application I use to exercise this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <termios.h>

#include "mymodule.h"


#define FILEPATH "/dev/mymodule0"

#define TEST_SIZE 10

int main(void)
{
  int fn = -1;
  char buf[TEST_SIZE];
  printf("Attempting to open file module file...\n");
  fn = open(FILEPATH, O_RDWR);
  if (fn < 0)
  {
    printf("Failed to open file!\n");
    return -1;
  }
  printf("Attempting to read from the file...\n");
  read(fn, &buf, TEST_SIZE);
  printf("Finished reading from file\n");
  return 0;
}
```

Here is the dmesg output when I

1. load the module
2. run the user application (it opens the file, attempts to read 10 characters, then exits)
3. write '1' to the sysfs attribute
4. unload the module

> ```
> [3217633.993937] Registering Driver
> [3217633.993995] Driver Initialized!
> [3217643.747791] Opened!
> [3217643.747800] Read!
> [3217643.747801] Wait for Completion
> [3217646.436780] Value is: 1
> [3217646.436792] Sent Completion
> [3217646.436806] After Completion
> [3217646.437010] Closed!
> [3217727.378388] Cleanup Module
> [3217727.378393] Check if we need to complete anything
> [3217727.378395] Send a completion!
> [3217727.378397] Unregistering Character Driver
> [3217727.378400] Give back all the numbers we requested
> [3217727.378402] Remove the class driver
> [3217727.378571] Release the class
> [3217727.378593] Finished Cleanup Module, Exiting
> ```

If I run the following commands:

1. load the module
2. run the user application
3. unload the module

> ```
> [3218223.442777] Registering Driver
> [3218223.442934] Driver Initialized!
> [3218229.378396] Opened!
> [3218229.378419] Read!
> [3218229.378422] Wait for Completion
> ```

then the module doesn't unload. If this were a real device, like a USB hard drive, it is possible that the user could remove the device in the middle of a read transaction. It seems like something is wrong, or perhaps I'm missing something. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Toby Speight: Thanks for the edits!

Answer (score 0):

While USB **device** can be removed *at any time*, its **driver** (e.g. kernel module) **cannot be unloaded** during certain operations with that device (e.g. reading). It is driver who reports to the upper level(e.g. filesystem) about absence of device.